# Executing Cucumber Tests Using Maven

Tags: java, android, maven, cucumber

I have been trying to get some cucumber tests written for an Android app running from command line. Since it is a maven project I have been using the following command:

```
mvn test
```

Maven then proceeds to run tests.BaseTest which builds successfully. Except no tests run because tests.BaseTest is not the test runner. The test runner is CucumberTest. To change this I then use the following command:

```
mvn -Dtest=CucumberTest -e
```

Maven now runs the test runner and decides to ruin my day by failing to build and throwing this mess at me (-e flag for stack trace, if yall need debug let me know):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project halo.home.qa: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project halo.home.qa: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:579)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Things I have tried: Ensuring the test class ended in the right suffix (*Test.java), adding the maven-surefire-plugin as a dependency in my pom file, changing version numbers of my dependencies in the pom file, going from java 11 to java 8.

This cucumber project works fine when I run this on IntelliJ, but I need to run through command line as well. Here is the project structure, and the CucumberTest runner:

```
Project
|
+--src
    |
    +--test
        |
        +--java
            |
            +--tests
            |    |
            |    +--BaseTest.java
            | 
            +-- CucumberTest.java
```

And the Runner:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import tests.BaseTest;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"html:target/Destination", "json:target/Destination/lpg/cucumber-json-report.json"},
        format = { "pretty", "html:target/Destination/lpg/cucumber-pretty"},
        features = {"src/test/resources"})

public class CucumberTest {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        BaseTest.runAppium();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void destroy () {
        BaseTest.destroy();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that problem occurs because you haven’t any Test in your cucumber class, try to create a test method (@Test) with anything.

Comment: I will give this a go tomorrow, dont have access to the project at the moment.

Comment: Seems I was missing the @Test Annotation... Thanks for your help!